# Сравнение аудио записей

Tags: аудио, нейронные-сети, распознавание-речи

Приветствую!

У меня есть эталонная аудио запись, с одним записанным словом, также есть вторая запись с тем же словом, но уже с посторонним шумом(скрипы, вздохи, акцент, ...) и также имеется третья запись(тоже с шумом) но уже с другим словом.
Мне нужно как-то сравнить вторую и третью запись с первой, и получить верный результат(Эдакий shazam для слов).

Какие существуют алгоритмы/библиотеки/сервисы для сравнения аудио записей/аудио потоков? Что можно почитать по этой теме?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько подходов

- Разбиваешь аудио на маленькие части, к каждой из которой преобразование Фурье. Получаешь 1-D вектор по частотам(фактически 2d, но считать одномерным, с толщиной)
- или берёшь просто данные как есть в файле

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ods/blog/327250/)
 - По вектору 1-д конволюцию, на первом слое будут карты толщиной как исходный вектор
 - Или просто схожестью по какой то метрике или паттерну

Если хочешь, перед этим очищай сигнал от помех в какой то звуковой проге и учись распознавать очищенный